# What would "close confinement" look like for a Saxon count being punished by Henry V of Germany in the early 1100s?

Tags: middle-ages, europe, nobility

While reading the Cambridge Medieval history collection I keep coming across 'confinement' or 'imprisonment' being used to punish or coerce nobles, kings, and even popes.

I'm wondering what the conditions would be for these high born people being confined or imprisoned. Would they be thrown in the dungeon with the common criminals, or could they expect better treatment?

As I'm assuming this would vary from place to place and over time, specific examples or accounts would be appreciated.

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)

Comment: Either one of "Europe" / "Middle-Ages" / "Or something similar" is awfully vague. Someone could be confined to his manor -- a kind of house arrest. He could be confined to somewhere close to the one doing the judgement. He could be confined to a dungeon cell. The rest is a matter of context. Your title indicates a rather more specific case. Why not tell us which one?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ejYmffwkuqo  King Richard had time and means to compose a song during imprisonment. (although a song  encouraging his vassals to pay his ransom was probably fine for his captor).

Comment: Which Henry V do you mean?

Answer (score 4):

*I'm going to address the question in the body, not the question in the title. I would have to do additional research to figure out which Henry V (I'm assuming [Henry V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_V,_Holy_Roman_Emperor), HRE 1095-1125; not a period or region where I have particular knowledge)*

It is impossible to say without reference to the actual citation.  I speculate that the author(?S?) are using the modern term [close confinement](https://www.lawinsider.com/dictionary/close-confinement#:%7E:text=of%20Close%20confinement-,Close%20confinement%20means%20confinement%20which%20deprives%20a%20prisoner%20of%20all,day%20out%20of%20the%20room.) to simplify a complex situation.

As a general rule, nobles were treated as nobles; they would not have been thrown in a dungeon or even subjected to the company of commoners.  What we think of as "prison" is a modern invention.  Commoners would have been dealt with quickly, usually through fines or death.

> Even the ‘smallest’ offences had serious punishments. The authorities feared the poor simply because there were many more poor than rich and any revolt could be potentially damaging – as the Peasants Revolt of 1381 proved. *[GSL](https://mfgsc-vic.libguides.com/c.php?g=916765&p=6609523)*

Nobles would have been guests of the house, but with communication somewhat controlled.

> High-ranking nobles and royalties were often the victims of imprisonment and, at times, had to wait many years until their ransom was paid. *[Incarceration](https://rowman.com/ISBN/9781793648297/Incarceration-and-Slavery-in-the-Middle-Ages-and-the-Early-Modern-Age-A-Cultural-Historical-Investigation-of-the-Dark-Side-in-the-Pre-Modern-World)*

(that source looks to be very apt for your question.)

One of the goals of warfare was to ransom a defeated enemy, and exchange him for wealth.  The last thing you wanted was for the opponent to die in your custody, forfeiting the potential investment.  It was entirely possible that you'd face that opponent again, and you'd want to ensure that your treatment was commensurate to what you were providing.

I rather suspect that the norm was to permit the captured noble freedom of movement *within bounds* and monitored communication in exchange for their parole that they would not attempt to escape.